# App stopped working google.appengine.ext.db Missing or insufficient permissions

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have a python27 app deployed to google app engine. Last deployment I did was 5 years ago so its been a while. The app used to work perfectly and so there was no reason for me to change anything. But today I noticed this error in the logs when I try to call the `fetch` (or any other) API of [google.appengine.ext.db](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/refdocs/google.appengine.ext.db):

```
from google.appengine.ext import db
db.Query(MyClass).fetch is giving error

Missing or insufficient permissions.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27g/174489198b39d9fb/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.3/webapp2.py", line 545, in dispatch
return method(*args, **kwargs)
File "/base/data/home/apps/s~buy-sell-books/15.387717900252501903/handlers/buy.py", line 134, in get
self.handle_search_by_zipcode_request()
File "/base/data/home/apps/s~buy-sell-books/15.387717900252501903/handlers/buy.py", line 100, in handle_search_by_zipcode_request
results = q.fetch(25)
File "/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27g/174489198b39d9fb/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/db/__init__.py", line 2161, in fetch
return list(self.run(limit=limit, offset=offset, **kwargs))
File "/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27g/174489198b39d9fb/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/db/__init__.py", line 2330, in next
return self.__model_class.from_entity(self.__iterator.next())
File "/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27g/174489198b39d9fb/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/datastore/datastore_query.py", line 3345, in next
next_batch = self.__batcher.next_batch(Batcher.AT_LEAST_OFFSET)
File "/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27g/174489198b39d9fb/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/datastore/datastore_query.py", line 3231, in next_batch
batch = self.__next_batch.get_result()
File "/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27g/174489198b39d9fb/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/apiproxy_stub_map.py", line 615, in get_result
return self.__get_result_hook(self)
File "/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27g/174489198b39d9fb/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/datastore/datastore_query.py", line 2930, in __query_result_hook
self._batch_shared.conn.check_rpc_success(rpc)
File "/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27g/174489198b39d9fb/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/datastore/datastore_rpc.py", line 1379, in check_rpc_success
raise _ToDatastoreError(err)
Error: Missing or insufficient permissions.
request_id: "5f00ffc92c00ff0db6e314a6016b0001737e6275792d73656c6c2d626f6f6b7300013135000100"
timestamp: "2020-07-04T18:23:40.969Z"
location: "/base/data/home/apps/s~buy-sell-books/15.387717900252501903/handlers/buy.py:13"
```

I can see following default service account in my console

[image]

I am wondering if anyone knows how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the solutions I came across mentioned the default service account. I also came across solutions that said to run `gcloud auth application-default login`. None of these solutions worked in my case. My default service account was already setup. It even had **Editor** role assigned to it. [This](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/default-service-account) doc says

> After you create an App Engine application, the App Engine default
> service account is created and used as the identity of the App Engine
> service. The App Engine default service account is associated with
> your Cloud project and executes tasks on behalf of your apps running
> in App Engine. By default, the App Engine default service account has
> the Editor role in the project. This means that any user account with
> sufficient permissions to deploy changes to the Cloud project can also
> run code with read/write access to all resources within that project.

and [this](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/access-control#auth-cloud-implicit-python) doc says

> This service account is created by Google when you create an App
> Engine app and is given full permissions to manage and use all Cloud
> services in a GCP project.

so what gives? Turns out I had to enter credit card details and enable billing.

[image]

Once I did that app started working back again!