# Deploying old app. Permissions required by db.Model

Tags: google-app-engine, google-app-engine-python

I'm attempting to deploy an app that has not has not been deployed since early-mid 2018.

I'm using `gcloud app deploy app.yaml index.yaml`.

The first thing I needed to do was remove the app name and version from the yaml file and use `--project name -v number` instead.

The next attempt responded with error 7: Cloud Build access not configured, which was fixed with a visit to the console website.

The next attempt responded that I needed to enable the Cloud Datastore API.

Then I updated the billing account of the app so that it was on the same billing account as my other apps that are costing me a few hundred a month.

Then there was a warning that Webapp2 needed to be updated to 2.5.2 which I did in the app.yaml and redeployed.

After the app was successfully deployed, when when attempting to use the application, a class derived from db.Model attempts to call all.get() and exception is raised.

```
File "/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27g/32fc9e2909a8cd9/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/db/__init__.py", line 2118, in get
return results.next()
File "/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27g/32fc9e2909a8cd9/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/db/__init__.py", line 2330, in next
return self.__model_class.from_entity(self.__iterator.next())
File "/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27g/32fc9e2909a8cd9/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/datastore/datastore_query.py", line 3345, in next
next_batch = self.__batcher.next_batch(Batcher.AT_LEAST_OFFSET)
File "/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27g/32fc9e2909a8cd9/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/datastore/datastore_query.py", line 3231, in next_batch
batch = self.__next_batch.get_result()
File "/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27g/32fc9e2909a8cd9/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/apiproxy_stub_map.py", line 615, in get_result
return self.__get_result_hook(self)
File "/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27g/32fc9e2909a8cd9/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/datastore/datastore_query.py", line 2930, in __query_result_hook
self._batch_shared.conn.check_rpc_success(rpc)
File "/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27g/32fc9e2909a8cd9/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/datastore/datastore_rpc.py", line 1379, in check_rpc_success
raise _ToDatastoreError(err)
Error: Missing or insufficient permissions.
```

My guess is that the app engine app does not have the correct permissions to access its datastore. I revisited the Datastore API page to review but I think it was trying to tell me that in app engine apps the permissions are implicit.

Anybody know what I have to do to be able to get my db.Model classes to be able to access the datastore?

**Update in response to some questions:**

The App was written when app engine was first released (before they acquired Firebase). I believe what is uses is simply called Datastore. As far as I'm aware there are no statements setting up the Database API. It was all automatic back then.

The App ussed a combineation of ndb and db imported into python like this.

```
from google.appengine.ext import ndb

class Classname(ndb.Model):
     property_name = ndb.TextProperty()
```

Comment: This question sounds similar, but it appears their problem was billing related. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62735688/app-stopped-working-google-appengine-ext-db-missing-or-insufficient-permissions. I believe my billing should be configured correctly.

Comment: What database are you using?  Firestore in database mode?  Cloud NDB?  Can you show your code for your Model construct and your Datastore API import?  If using Firestore, did you instantiate the database with your credentials?

Comment: What is your runtime environment? Can you share app.yaml file?

Comment: The error seems related to a `db` call, not an `ndb` call.  Can you show your code for your `db` model?

Comment: I had a similar errors on an old app and this post solved my problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59210059/datastoreexception-missing-or-insufficient-permissions-on-superseded-cloud-da/59216570

Comment: thanks @user2428107 I did see your question and confirmed that I did have a gserviceaccount account user.

Comment: @vitooh a sample of the app.yaml https://pastebin.com/8aHgMXq2

Comment: @GAE fan. I use a mix of ndb and db in this app. when nbd was released I did not want to rewrite classes that were already manually pushing things into and out of memcache.

Comment: @JayKyburz are you sure the error is form this code sample? The error seems to be from db while this code contain only ndb...

Comment: I don't think you need to list `webapp2` in your `app.yaml` nor need to and enabling Datastore really just means adding a billing acct. Couple of suggestions: 1) Go back to IAM and not only confim that service acct is there, but it has EDITOR access, and 2) try not to mix both `db` and `ndb` code... here's a migration guide: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/ndb/db_to_ndb ... let us know how it goes!

Comment: @wescpy I double checked and you were right,the gservice account was there but did not have the correct permission.